# CSS change background color on hover

Tags: css

Why is this not working?

```
            <div class="homePrizes">
                <div class="homeCredit">
                    1250 Points
                </div>
                <div class="homePrize">
                    Prize1
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.homePrizes {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    line-height:30px;
}

.homeCredit {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#F90;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
}

.homePrize {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    float:right;
}

.homePrizes:hover {
    background-color:#FC6;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is because of the floats, `.homePrizes` does not take up any space. You have to manually set a height for `.homePrizes` or align it differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `.homePrizes` has no content that isn't floating, doesn't have an explicit height, and doesn't apply any of the [techniques for containing floats](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59):

The container has a height of 0. As a result, there is no area for the pointer to hover over, and no visible space to have a background colour.

Change to:

```
.homePrizes {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    line-height:30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That said, since it is non-interactive, adding a hover effect would send the wrong signals the user. That sort of colour change shouts *click me* at the user.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.homePrizes {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    line-height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

You need to add `overflow:hidden` to the parent div to expand its height and cover the children divs

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto;` to .homePrizes will work.

Reason:
The child of .homeprizes are all float, that leads to the browser consider that to be 0 height element. Adding overflow:auto will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a quick edit to:

`.homePrizes {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    line-height:30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}`

Good luck!