# Best way to create link inside td with onMouseOver function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which includes a `td` with an `onMouseOver` function that changes the background color of the `td`. The text inside the td is a link. The problem I am having is that the link appears "highlighted" when the mouse hovers over the `td`, but can't be clicked on unless the mouse is hovering over the link itself. In other words, there is kind of a "buffer" zone around the link text but inside the boundaries of the `td` where the background color is changed but the cursor remains the standard pointer (and the link cannot be clicked). Is there a way to cause the entire `td` to be a link, or would I have to use two different images to get the desired effect?

Example code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onMouseOver="bgColChange();" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <a href="www.mysite.com/locn1">Location 1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can do something like: anchor_element { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

Comment: You can also use CSS to change the background. See [CSS change background color on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5058115/12892) for example.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="myTD0" onMouseOver="bgColChange();" style="background-color:red;cursor:pointer;" onClick="document.getElementById('myLink0').click();">
            <a href="www.mysite.com/locn1" id="myLink0">Location 1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See I have added `onClick` on `td` with id of anchor tag

```
 onclick="document.getElementById('myLink0').click();"
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepak0143/ZrAQm/)

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want a TD element with a link inside of it and you want to:

1. change BG color when hovered
2. make entire TD element clickable for the link

The first thing to note is you're using inline JavaScript.  That means you're placing raw JavaScript code inside your HTML.  That is not a good practice or convention to follow.  In the last several years the JavaScript community has stepped away from inline JavaScript.

Instead, the better approach is called "unobtrusive JavaScript" which is a fancy name that means you give your HTML elements class/ID names that you can reference in your JavaScript and CSS files.

This [Wikipedia Article on Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is pretty good at showing what the differences are.  The takeaway is that unobtrusive JavaScript is the preferred practice and should be used as much as possible.

I know there are unique situations where inline JS is still necessary, but you're particular problem doesn't need any JavaScript.  You simply need to use some specific CSS.  Often times the best solution is the simplest.

```
# HTMl file
# ----------------------------------------
<table class="custom">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="www.mysite.com/locn1">Location 1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


# CSS file
# # ----------------------------------------
.custom {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Give TD element padding so you can see that link expands properly */
.custom td {
    border: 1px solid black; /* For visual aid */
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Change background color on hover of TD element */
.custom td:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}

/* Change link color when hovering over TD element */
.custom td:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

/* Make link expand to entire TD element (its parent) */
.custom td a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Here is a JS Fiddle example that works without using any JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/xs5q4/).

This solution is preferred because it does not use JavaScript and is much easier to understand as another developer.

You only need to add a custom class to your TABLE element so that you can attach CSS styles to it.  I've added several comments in the JS Fiddle so be sure to check them out.  You can also play with the JS Fiddle example to help you understand it further.

Comment: Thanks. There still seems to be the problem of the buffer zone around whatever's inside the td. It seems like the td padding (20px in the example you provided) creates the buffer zone, so unless I were to reduce the padding to 0px I would still have the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the buffer zone.  If you click anywhere in the TD element it activates the link on the JS Fiddle example. Can you explain it a little better so I understand what you're trying to do? I thought you just wanted a link that is activated when clicking anywhere in the TD element.

Comment: I guess you'll have to forgive me, I'm not really an expert on HTML. Doesn't the TD encompass everything inside the table's boundaries, or does the padding set limits on the TD's borders? Currently, if I hover over any part of the table (inside the visible border), the background color changes, but the link isn't activated unless I click directly on the link (or to the right of it).